# Arrays concept in JAVA

Tags: java

Consider the two ways of declaring an array type variable in Java:

1) Syntax : `dataType[] arrayRefVar;`

Example:

```
double[] myList;
```

2) Syntax: `dataType arrayRefVar[];`

Example:

```
double myList[];
```

Why is the first syntax preferred over the second?

Comment: whichever is more readable for you and your fellow coders. No behavior/performance difference except readability.

Comment: @JunedAhsan: Well, whichever is most readable for you *and everyone who reads your code*.

Comment: format content as per posting guidelines.

Comment: @JonSkeet True, there is no fun without bothering fellow coders ;-)

Comment: The best way of writing the sequence of the array definition components, is to write them the way you spell them: int[] foo is spelled "integer array foo", while int foo[] is spelled "integer foo array", which is not as natural as the first concept.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, all the type information is in one place - the type of the variable is "array of `dataType`" so that's what the `dataType[]` says.

Why would you have two aspects of the type information in different places - one with the element type name and one with the variable?

Note that you can do *really* confusing things:

```
int[] x[]; // Equivalent to int[][] x
```

and

```
int foo()[] // Equivalent to int[] foo()
```

Ick!

Also note that the array syntax is closer to the generic syntax if you later want to use a collection type instead of an array. For example:

```
String[] foo
```

to

```
List<String> foo
```

Basically, the `int foo[]` syntax was only included in Java to make it look more like C and C++. Personally I think that was a mistake - it can never be removed from the language now, despite the fact that it's strongly discouraged :(

Answer (score 0):

They are 100% functionally identical but the first form isn't allowed in C or C++ and it's easier to tell that it is an array (in my opinion)

```
int[] a; // <-- not valid in C (or C++)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only legal in Java"? It's legal in other languages too, and both are legal in Java...

Comment: @JonSkeet Edited. Read better? I was trying to say it wasn't legal C or C++.

Comment: I suggest you say exactly that then - given just how many languages there are, including obscure ones, I strongly suspect that Java wasn't the first language ever to use `Foo[]` for an array of `Foo` elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference its just preference of writing came from `C` and `C++` languages.

Look at JLS on Arrays:

> The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the
>   declaration, or as part  of the declarator for a particular
>   variable,or both.